# (JAVA) moving clipping area by keylistener

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, clipping

My goal is moving clipping area 10 pixels at a time using arrow keys. I got the image on the panel and the clipping area is there too, but the thing is that the clipping area won't move. Here is my code, and I hope to learn what's wrong with it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class clipping_area extends JFrame{
    clipping_area(){
        setTitle("OpenChallenge");
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        add(new panelOC());
    }
    class panelOC extends JPanel{
        int xAxis=0;
        int yAxis=0;
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Image img=(new ImageIcon("images/image1.jpg")).getImage();
            g.setClip(100+10*xAxis,100+10*yAxis,50,50);
            g.drawImage(img,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
        }
        panelOC(){
            requestFocus();
            addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent KE){
                    if(KE.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                        yAxis-=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if(KE.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                        yAxis+=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if(KE.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                        xAxis-=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                    else if(KE.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                        xAxis+=1;
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new clipping_area();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Java, you might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: Don't load resources from within any `paint` method, paint methods are suppose to, well, paint, loading resources like this could slow down the paint process

Answer (score 2):

`KeyListener` is a real pain in the, well, focus area.  If the component it is attached to is not focusable AND has keyboard focus, it won't trigger events, that's the way it's designed.  Instead, use the Key Bindings API which has been designed to overcome this.

See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Be wary of modifying the `clip` of a `Graphics` context, a `Graphics` context is shared resource, meaning that it will be past to other components.  You could also, if you're not careful, size the clip in such away as to paint beyond the range of the component, causing some weird graphics glitches, personally, I stay away from it.

If you use `ImageIO.read` instead, you can get a reference to a `BufferedImage` and use `getSubImage` to "fake" it instead

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import static javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ClippingArea extends JFrame {

    ClippingArea() {
        setTitle("OpenChallenge");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        add(new PanelOC());
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class PanelOC extends JPanel {

        int xAxis = 0;
        int yAxis = 0;
        private BufferedImage img;

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500, 500);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (img != null) {

                int width = 50;
                if (xAxis + width > img.getWidth()) {
                    width = img.getWidth() - xAxis;
                }
                int height = 50;
                if (yAxis + height > img.getHeight()) {
                    height = img.getHeight() - yAxis;
                }

                if (width > 0 && height > 0) {

                    BufferedImage subImage = img.getSubimage(xAxis, yAxis, width, height);
                    g.drawImage(subImage, xAxis, yAxis, this);

                }

            }

        }

        protected void registerKeyBinding(String name, KeyStroke keyStroke, Action action) {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(keyStroke, name);
            am.put(name, action);
        }

        public PanelOC() {

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\hold\\thumbnails\\_cg_836___Tilting_Windmills___by_Serena_Clearwater.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            registerKeyBinding("moveClip.up", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), new YKeyAction(-10));
            registerKeyBinding("moveClip.down", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), new YKeyAction(10));
            registerKeyBinding("moveClip.left", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), new XKeyAction(-10));
            registerKeyBinding("moveClip.right", KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), new XKeyAction(10));
        }

        public class XKeyAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int delta;

            public XKeyAction(int delta) {
                this.delta = delta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                xAxis += delta;
                if (yAxis > getWidth()) {
                    yAxis = getWidth() - 50;
                } else if (yAxis < 0) {
                    yAxis = 0;
                }
                repaint();
            }

        }

        public class YKeyAction extends AbstractAction {

            private int delta;

            public YKeyAction(int delta) {
                this.delta = delta;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                yAxis += delta;
                if (yAxis > getHeight()) {
                    yAxis = getHeight() - 50;
                } else if (yAxis < 0) {
                    yAxis = 0;
                }
                repaint();
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                ClippingArea ca = new ClippingArea();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

You should also be creating and modiying your UI from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a keylistener on a panel use a AWTEventListener (which will grab all events of a particular type

```
java.awt.Toolkit toolkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    toolkit.addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent ae) {
            if (ae instanceof KeyEvent) {
                KeyEvent KE = (KeyEvent) ae;
                if (KE.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED) {
                    switch(KE.getKeyCode()) {
                        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                            yAxis -= 1;
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                            yAxis += 1;
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                            xAxis -= 1;
                            break;
                        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                            xAxis += 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        }
    }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

And a second edit, I replaced your if statements with a switch ( its significantly cleaner to read and easier to modify later.

Comment: Only the given java application has focus, and reading through the code it appears that he is trying to force the focus in a single component application. I am assuming his intention is to gather all key-events.

Comment: And what happens if the OP adds text components?  You'll pick the key events from those?  What about menus? Using a global listener has it's places, but this really isn't one of them, especially when there is already an API available which can solve the issue simply and easily...just saying...

Comment: While it may solve the issue simply and easily for either of us, you can see from a mile off that this guy is fairly fresh to java, and looking at the code dosnt even have a IDE up and running, not exactly going to to instruct him to build 8 classes and throw him in the proverbial deep end.

Comment: All the more reason to provide the OP with "right" answer, not just one that "fulfills" the moment - after all, you don't want other people to have to clean up the mess that you've created...

Comment: thanks for your help. As you said, I am fairly fresh to this. I think my JPanel is not getting the focus it needs.(I've tested it by making it print something on console if keyPressed worked but it wouldn't print anything.) I tried setFocusable = true and requestFocusInWindow.

Comment: The jpanel will not capable of getting direct focus so it wont receive any events from a keylistener. Both answers here will work (mine should simply replace your keylistener, and then all tutorials you find online will then apply. but it will grab ALL keyboard events in your application. )